# JavaFX panel resizing

Tags: java, javafx, resize

I have a JavaFX App in its main window you find a splitPane, click and option to the left and content is displayed in the right.

I can't get the AnchorPane with the content to resize correctly.

With this code it goes bigger as you resize the main window, but when you make it smaller it stays big.

Method for showing new content in the right:

```
public void setShow(AnchorPane pane){
    pane.prefWidthProperty().bind(show.widthProperty());
    pane.maxWidthProperty().bind(show.widthProperty());
    pane.prefHeightProperty().bind(show.heightProperty());
    pane.maxHeightProperty().bind(show.heightProperty());
    show.getChildren().setAll(pane);
}
```

And this is one of my contents controller:

```
public class ProductosController implements Initializable {

@FXML private AnchorPane panel;
@FXML private TableView<ProductoData> tabla;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    Producto producto = new Producto();

    tabla.prefWidthProperty().bind(panel.widthProperty());
    tabla.maxWidthProperty().bind(panel.widthProperty());
    tabla.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
    tabla.setItems(producto.getProductosOL());
    }
}
```

And here a some screenshots to show you the problem:

**Original size**
[image: SC1]

**Bigger**
[image: SC2]

**When you back to small**
[image: SC3]

Comment: Avoid AnchorPane.  It’s pretty close to an absolute layout, which is going to cause problems like what you’re seeing.  Consider using a BorderPane instead, where the table is the center child and the “Productos” label is the top child.

Comment: I tried with BorderPane now, it wont get smaller.
MainWindow actually has HBox + SplitPane. "Productos" label is inside the Hbox.

Comment: I would avoid the use of HBox and VBox altogether for this particular layout.  They don’t make child nodes stretch in the direction of the box.  On the other hand, a BorderPane’s center node will always stretch.